# Как разрешить запросы в nginx только с определенного домена

Tags: linux, node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx

Использую на сервере nginx для размещения node js / react js приложения
Фронт стоит на домене app.site а бэкэнд стоит на домене api.site

Вопрос - как разрешить запросы к api.site только с адреса app.site?
Не с ip адреса а именно с доменного имени

Comment: Вы в api средствами nginx или приложения ставите CORS заголовки, такие как Access-Control-Allow-Origin ? В этом заговоловке как раз указывается с какого домена вы позволяете делать запросы. Дополнительно можно проверять заголовок Referer. Но вы же понимаете, что это работает только для честных браузеров и не позволяет напрямую указать ваш API на сайте с другим доменом. Любое обращение не из браузера, а программно, отлично подделывает любые заголовки и защиты от этого не может быть

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно указать в заголовке, с какого домена можно отправлять запросы? Заголовки использую при помощи nginx

Если это не особо хороший вариант защиты, то каким образом можно защититься сторонних запросов?

Comment: В заголовке Access-Control-Allow-Origin указывается либо '*' - с любого домена, либо домен с которого можно. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что́ вы имеете в виду под словами "с домена". "На домен" ещё более-менее понятно, но "с домена"...

Answer (score 0):

Заголовок Referrer говорит бэку откуда запрос, но его легко подделать. Поэтому реализуйте защиту бэка на уровне приложения выдавая и проверяя токены (ключи).